# How can I link the results to the input fields when they are generated by the user?

Tags: javascript, html

The goal I have is to allow the user to create as many rows as needed, each of them with their own name, color1 and color2 values. And then get that information and display it in the results box. To illustrate that I've made a quick and simple example with more or less what I got so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/dkcxsqof/11/

```js
const mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");
const result_box = document.getElementById("results");
const addButton = document.getElementById("add_button");
let count = document.querySelectorAll(".item_element");

function createElements() {
  // create the element container
  const item_element = document.createElement("div");
  mainContainer.insertBefore(item_element, addButton)
  item_element.setAttribute("class", "item_element");
  // give the element container an incremented id
  item_element.setAttribute("id", "item_element" + count.lenght++);
  
  // create text input
  const text_input = document.createElement("input");
  text_input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  item_element.appendChild(text_input);
  
  // create color input I
  const color_input1 = document.createElement("input");
  color_input1.setAttribute("type", "color");
  item_element.appendChild(color_input1);
  
  // create color input II
  const color_input2 = document.createElement("input");
  color_input2.setAttribute("type", "color");
  item_element.appendChild(color_input2);
  
  // create remove button
  const remove_button = document.createElement("div");
  remove_button.setAttribute("class", "remove");
  remove_button.textContent = "-";
    item_element.appendChild(remove_button);
  
  // create line 1
  const line1 = document.createElement("span");
  line1.innerHTML = "The first Color Is (input_color1) and belongs to (input_text) <br>";
  result_box.appendChild(line1);
  
  // create line 2
  const line2 = document.createElement("span");
  line2.innerHTML = "The second Color Is (input_color2) and belongs to (input_text) <br>";
  result_box.appendChild(line2);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F6F6F2;
}

h3 {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6FB3B8;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.item_box {
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  background-color: #388087;
  padding: 3px;
}

.item_element {
  background: #BADFE7;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 5px
}

.remove {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f55b5b;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #BADFE7;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.add {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #5bf568;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #388087;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.result_box {
  width: calc(95% - 10px);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #102426;
  color: #C2EDCE;
  font-family: monospace;
}


input[type="text"] {
  width: 20%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input[type="color"] {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px 4px 5px 4px;
}

p {
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #388087;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<h3>List Of Items</h3>
<div class="item_box" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="add" id="add_button" onclick="createElements()">+</div>
</div>

<h3>List Of Results</h3>
<div class="result_box" id="results"></div>

<p>The goal is to input a color group (ex. 'cold colors') in the input text, then select two colors.</p>
<p>After that, the whole information should display below.</p>
<p>The '+' and '-' buttons should add or remove them.</p>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this? It's not quite clear what you're asking.

Comment: @mykaf yeah, how can I link the results to the input fields when they are generated by the user

Comment: Add an event listener, depending on *when* you want to retrieve the results, then gather the values of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

To have control of events occurring when the input value of your newly created controls changed, requires you to add a `change` event listener to the element you wish to monitor.

I slightly changed your code but mostly I better factored:

- The logEvent function, printing a line on the results box
- The createNewRow function, creates and returns the new row element containing its children and the corresponding event listener already attached
- The above said function, defines the listener for the change event of all the input controls and for the click event of the remove button

In general the recipe is using the function `addEventListener` on an element to listen to a specific event (in this case: `click` and `change`) and inside the function using `event.target` to get the element triggering the event.

```js
let idCounter = 0;

//adds a new row to the input container
function addNewRow(){
  const mainContainer = document.getElementById("mainContainer");
  const newRow = createNewRow(++idCounter);
  mainContainer.append(newRow)
  logEvent(`New input row added (id:${newRow.id})`);
}

//logs the passed msg inside the results box
function logEvent(msg){
  const newEvent = document.createElement("div");
  newEvent.innerText = msg;
  document.getElementById('results').append(newEvent);
}

//creates and returns the element for a new input row
function createNewRow(idNumber) {  

  //function bound to the change event listener of all input controls
  function valueChanged(event){
    const changedControl = event.target;
    const changedRow = changedControl.parentElement;
    logEvent(
      `input row (id:${changedRow.id}) ` +
      `changed value for the colour control (ctrl:${changedControl.dataset.control})`);
  }
  
  //function bound to the click event listener of all remove buttons
  function removeRow(event){    
    logEvent(
      `input row (id:${event.target.parentElement.id}) removed`);
    event.target.parentElement.remove();
  }

  //parent element for the new row
  const item_element = document.createElement("div");
  //the id of the row element gets composed as this using the idNumber passed to the function  
  item_element.setAttribute('id', `item_element_${idNumber}`);
  item_element.setAttribute('class', 'item_element');  
  item_element.addEventListener('change', valueChanged);
  
  //control1 inside the new row
  const text_input = document.createElement('input');
  text_input.dataset.control = 'control1';
  text_input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  item_element.appendChild(text_input);
    
  //control2 inside the new row    
  const color_input1 = document.createElement('input');
  color_input1.dataset.control = 'control2';
  color_input1.setAttribute('type', 'color');
  item_element.appendChild(color_input1);
    
  //control3 inside the new row    
  const color_input2 = document.createElement('input');
  color_input2.dataset.control = 'control3';
  color_input2.setAttribute('type', 'color');
  item_element.appendChild(color_input2);
    
  //remove button
  const remove_button = document.createElement('div');
  remove_button.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
  remove_button.textContent = '-';
  remove_button.addEventListener('click', removeRow);
  item_element.appendChild(remove_button);
    
  return item_element;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F6F6F2;
}

h3 {
  margin: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #6FB3B8;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.item_box {
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
  background-color: #388087;
  padding: 3px;
}

.item_element {
  background: #BADFE7;
  height: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.remove {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f55b5b;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #BADFE7;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin: 5px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.add {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #5bf568;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: #388087;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18pt;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.result_box {
  width: calc(95% - 10px);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #102426;
  color: #C2EDCE;
  font-family: monospace;
}


input[type="text"] {
  width: 20%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
}

input[type="color"] {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px 4px 5px 4px;
}

p {
  padding-left: 50px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #388087;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<h3>List Of Items</h3>
<div class="item_box" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="add" id="add_button" onclick="addNewRow()">+</div>
</div>

<h3>Events:</h3>
<div class="result_box" id="results"></div>
```